# DataTables: Ajax include space in search filter

Tags: ajax, search, datatables, space

I have this code but i can't do a search filter with space or comma,
I need do a smart search with ajax on datatables

Datatables ajax code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
oDtable = $('#exc').dataTable({
    "scrollX": true,
    "scrollY": 300,
    "oSearch": { "bSmart": false, "bRegex": true },
    "processing": true,
    "serverSide": true,
    "ajax": "/ajax/getJSONResultsForDT?table=eventos&primaryKey=id",
    "columns": [
        {"data": 'nombre'},
        {"data": 'descripcion'},
        {"data": 'fecha_inicio'},
        {"data": 'fecha_fin'},
        {"data": "created_by"},
        {"data": "updated_by"},
        {"data": null}, //6 y 7
        {"data": null}
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            "targets": [6],
            "orderable": false,
            "render": function (data) {
                $id = data.id;

                return '<button class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit-modal">Edit</button>';
            }
        },
        {
            "targets": [7],
            "orderable": false,
            "render": function (data) {
                return '<a class="btn btn-danger" data-fancybox-type="iframe">' + 'Delete' + '</a>';
            }
        }],
    "bPaginate": true,
    "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
});
```

});

don't know what else to write
HHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH

Comment: Please remember to format the code in your question. http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting

Comment: You're using serverside processing, so you need to pass the search term to the `getJSONResultsForDT` using `fnServerParams` or adding it to you quesrystring. Also, why have you added all that crap at the bottom of your question? Is it supposed to help?